# How to update MicroMeter gauge according to labels

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, gauge, micrometer

I use MicroMeter gauges in a Spring Boot 2 application to track statuses of objects. On status change, the `statusArrived()` method is called. This function should update the gauge related to that object.

Here is my current implementation:

```java
public class PrometheusStatusLogger {

    private int currentStatus;

    public void statusArrived(String id, int value) {
        currentStatus = value;
        Tags tags = Tags.of("product_id", id);

        Gauge.builder("product_status",this::returnStatus)
          .tags(tags)
          .strongReference(true)
          .register(Metrics.globalRegistry);
    }

    private int returnStatus(){
        return currentStatus;
    }    
}
```

This works quite well, but the problem is that when this method is called, all gauges values are updated. I would like only the gauge with the given `product_id` to be updated.

**Input**:

```
statusArrived(1, 2);
statusArrived(2, 3);
```

**Current output**:

```
product_status{product_id=1} 3
product_status{product_id=2} 3
```

All gauges are updated

**Desired output**:

```
product_status{product_id=1} 2
product_status{product_id=2} 3
```

Only the gauge with the given product_id tag is updated.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since all your gauges are referencing the same `currentStatus`, when the new value comes in, all the gauge's source is changed. Instead use a map to track all the current status by id:

```java
public class PrometheusStatusLogger {

    private Map<String, Integer> currentStatuses =  new HashMap<>();

    public void statusArrived(String id, int value) {
        if(!currentStatuses.containsKey(id)) {
            Tags tags = Tags.of("product_id", id);
            Gauge.builder("product_status",currentStatuses, map -> map.get(id))
                    .tags(tags)
                    .register(Metrics.globalRegistry);
        }
        currentStatuses.put(id, value);
    }

}
```